# How to update a field on its own in few days?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where I am accepting payments from users. The due date is 30 days from the payment date. Initially the is_due field is false but I want it to change to true without updating manually when due date is just seven days away. I have got no solution even after looking up everywhere.

models

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='name')
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, default = datetime.datetime.now())
    due_date = models.DateField()
    payment_mode = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PaymentModes,null=True,blank=True)
    collected_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete = None, related_name='collected_by')
    is_due = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.due_date = self.date + monthdelta(1)
        dt = self.due_date-datetime.date.today()
        if dt.days <=7:
            self.is_due = True
        else:
            self.is_due = False

        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You don't. That's why you should *not* use an `is_due` field in the first place: it simply is data duplication, which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: What am I supposed to do then?

Comment: remove the `is_due` field, and annotate the queryset with these properties (or use a property). You can move the annotation in a manager if you need i0t often.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually *not* a good idea to schedule tasks to update rows, since that is not a very robust solution. If you schedule tasks in memory, a restart of the server will result in scheduled tasks not being triggered. You can use tools like *celery* to use "persistent" scheduled tasks, but that requires some effort to set it up, and furthermore both solutions are not "exact": it can take some extra seconds before the tasks is triggered.

The same might holds for setting the `due_date` to the `date` and one month: you here have *data duplication*, which tends to be bad. If `due_date` is always `date` with one extra month, you are wasting disk space. Furthermore the `save()` function is not always triggered: for example if you update in bulk, Django will *bypass* the save function, and thus your data might be inconsistent.

Probably easiest way to handle this is annotating your queryset, for example in a manager:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

class PaymentManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            is_due=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(due_date__lt=datetime.date.today()-timedelta(days=7)),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )

class Payment(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='name')
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, default=date.today)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    payment_mode = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PaymentModes,null=True,blank=True)
    collected_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete = None, related_name='collected_by')

    objects = PaymentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.due_date = self.date + monthdelta(1)
        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that the default of your `date = DateField(..)` should be `date.today`, *not* <s>`date.today()`</s>, since by calling it, it will set as default date the date when you have started the server, not the date at creation.